# How to make type classes resolve for base/abstract class?

Tags: scala, typeclass

Say I've a base abstract class and 2 case classes extending it.

```
sealed abstract class Base extends Product with Serializable

case class A(d: String) extends Base
case class B(d: Int) extends Base
```

And I have also a type class on `A` and `B`, for example

```
trait Show[T] {
  def show(t: T): String
}

object Show {
  def apply[T](t: T)(implicit show: Show[T]): String = show.show(t)

  implicit val showA: Show[A] = new Show[A] {
    def show(t: A): String = "A"
  }

  implicit val showB: Show[B] = new Show[B] {
    def show(t: B): String = "B"
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that, in my code I get `A` and `B` from deserialization and they have type `Base`. In this case scala fail to resolve the typeclasses because there's not type classes defined on `Base`.

I could solve this problem by defining an instance on `Base` and do a pattern match but IMO in this way we'd better not use typeclasses at all.

Is there any tricks that we can make scala resolve type classes for a base class? 
Thanks.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but you can definitely do this using Shapeless or Magnolia (http://magnolia.work/) and deriving an instance for the sealed trait. If you're using cats you can check out kittens https://github.com/milessabin/kittens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such trick. Type has to be statically known because it is the compiler who resolves the typeclass instance.

As you said an instance for `Base` that will resolve proper instance has to be created. It can be done manually but there might be better ways to do it. Maybe someone can provide a better answer on how to do it nicely, but fundamentally the instance for `Base` is needed.